# Geolocation doesn't work in browser

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to run the page, it displayed a message which is this page didn't load Google map correctly. See the JavaScript. The browser already had a permission to access my location. But I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: What is the error message exactly? What browser did you get this error in? "See the JavaScript." - nothing in your javascript refers to "didn't load google map correctly" - so what is the error

Comment: Your code works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/m1jwzc2b/

Comment: is you local server on https or on http? google only allows ssl connections since middle of 2016. i had this problem too and had to refactor my apps to use ssl

Comment: @Arnau  
 
I got the API KEY, but the page does not display my location. It says the Geolocation service failed.

Comment: @JaromandaX  After I put the API KEY it only, works on the PC. MY location doesn't 't work on the Phone browser.

Comment: is the phone browser chrome? then see @mtizziani comment

Comment: @mtizziani How could you change it to ssl? because I want to run my code on the Phone browser - FireFox-

Comment: @ralkutbi: whats the server behind? apache? iis? something else? you need an ssl certificate, enable ssl in your web-server and configure ssl for the domain. google helps with configuration, it's too long for comments inside here

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good, but you have forgotten to substitute the API KEY. So, you have to obtain a KEY in this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
and then subsitute the KEY in `YOUR_API_KEY`:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

Comment: I got the API KEY, but the page does not display my location. It says the Geolocation service failed.